# Real CPU usage - Task Manager

Tags: cpu, task-manager

I have question about CPU usage, why does the Windows Task Manager shows me different CPU usage? I tried make some stress test where it showed me CPU usage 100%, but Task Manager shows only 65% usage.

Windows 8.1 full updated,
CPU: AMD A10 5750M, laptop

[image: http://s11.postimg.org/bddxe89vm/stresstest.jpg]

Comment: Can you provide a full screenshot of Task Manager's Performance tab while you're running the stress test?

Answer (score 4):

Your stress test software only support two core calculation, but your CPU 5750M is 4 core based, so even your stress test software show 100% full load, it actually loading 2/4 core only, outcome is 50%, plus other application running in background, that way you can see 65%

You can verify that by using Task Manager `Processes` slot by CPU (below screenshot found from Internet running XP, but it is the same for Windows 7, for Windows 8 or after, switch to `Details`)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Burn Hiren's boot cd/usb on there are several diagnostic programs which you can run to determine the state of your system.

However a stress test will always (or at least should) always stress your system to near breaking point so of course it will push your CPU to 100% more than likely Task manager is showing you, your current CPU usage. The two programs are used for different things.

A task managed just monitors and reports, a stress or bench test does the opposite and pushes all of your system's hardware and in some cases software to their limit and then generates a report on what their limit is.

http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd-on-usb-disk